# Listener problems with ItemWriteListener and ChunkListner

Tags: spring-batch

I have a really nebulous problem concerning listeners within a spring batch chunk process.

My chunk configuration is listed below:

```
<batch:chunk
       reader="processMidxDbItemReader"
       processor="midxItemProcessor"
       writer="midxCompositeItemWriter"
       processor-transactional="false"
       reader-transactional-queue="false"
       skip-limit="${cmab.batch.skip.limit}"
       commit-interval="#{jobParameters['toProcess']==T(de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.util.CmabConstants).TYPE_POSTAUSGANG ? '${consumer.global.pa.midx.readCount}' : '${consumer.global.pe.midx.readCount}' }"
       cache-capacity="20">
    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        <batch:include class="de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.util.CmabProcessMidxException" />
    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
    <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
        <batch:include class="de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.util.CmabTechnicalMidxException" />
        <batch:include class="de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.util.CmabTechnicalException" />
    </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
    <batch:retry-listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="logRetryListener"/>
    </batch:retry-listeners>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener>
            <bean id="midxProcessSkipListener" class="de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.core.batch.listener.CmabDbSkipListener" scope="step">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{jobParameters['errorStatus']}" type="java.lang.String"/>
            </bean>
        </batch:listener>
        <batch:listener>
            <bean id="cmabChunkListener" class="de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.core.batch.listener.CmabChunkListener" scope="step"/>
        </batch:listener>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:chunk>
```

The **midxProcessSkipListener** implements ItemProcessListener and ItemWriteListener with all the override methods. 
The **cmabChunkListener** Bean implements ChunkListener.

So what is my problem:
If a write error occured I would expected that...

- a) the `afterChunkError` of "cmabChunkListener" is called
- b) the `onWriteError` of "midxProcessSkipListener" is called.

But unfortunately **just** the `afterChunkError` method is called. The `onWriteError` method is ignored?!?

If I comment the `cmabChunkListener` Bean within my configuration (see above) then the `onWriteError` of the `midxProcessSkipListener` is indeed called.

What could cause this behaviour? Why isn't it possible to have two seperate listener within the Chunk process?
My aim is that **both** methods will be called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,

Bodo Stockschlaeder

Comment: could you add the stack trace?

Comment: Hi, I haven't any stack trace because the process does not throw any error. I just observe that the onWriteError method is not called as long as the ChunkListener is registered. And this is the problem I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Can you log the error with `logger.error("exception encountered", e)` or `e.printStackTrace()` and then add the output here? Realistically, you rarely ever want to "eat" exceptions without logging them in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiousity: The solution in my case is to define the listener out of the chunk configuration, means within the batch tasklet.

```
                    </batch:chunk>
                    <batch:listeners>
                        <batch:listener ref="midxStepListener"/>
                        <batch:listener>
                            <bean id="cmabChunkListener" class="de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.core.batch.listener.CmabChunkListener" scope="step"/>
                        </batch:listener>
                    </batch:listeners>
             </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>
```

This solution worked for me :-)

Nevertheless thanks for the responses.

Kind regards,
Bodo